# Getting the the value of a row in a specific column

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

given is a excel sheet with the following details:

```
   Country    Name       Year
   
   Germany    Lisa       1992
   Spain      Sofia      1992
   USA        Thomas     1992
   Sweden     Hubert     1994
   Germany    Jossy      1995
```

Now I want to have a python function where you use the year as a parameter and it gives returns you back the values of the row.

So for example `def giveDetails(1992)` then it should return me Germany Lisa and Span Sofia

Or `giveDetails(1994)` --> return Sweden , Hubert.

I know that you have to convert in in a Pandas dataframe and iterate through the rows and columns but I don't know how to get the value of the  the columns "country" and "name" while the value of "year" is given.

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Do you have anything so far... have you loaded the sheet into a pandas DataFrame for instance?

Comment: hi. yes sheet is loaded into pandas dataframe




`df_orga = pd.read_csv("Wiener_Stadtbuecher/organisations.csv" )
df_pers = pd.read_csv("Wiener_Stadtbuecher/persons.csv" )
df_kin_rel = pd.read_csv("Wiener_Stadtbuecher/pers_kin_relations.csv" )
df_off_rel = pd.read_csv("Wiener_Stadtbuecher/persorg_off_Relations.csv" )
df_staff_rel = pd.read_csv("Wiener_Stadtbuecher/pers_staff_relations.csv" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter using pandas

```
fil_year= df['year']== 'the year you want'

df.loc[fil_year]
```

Comment: why do I get a "False when I use: 1992 in df.Year? 

Because df.Year contains 1992. But it returns me False. Why?

Comment: @Tommy not sure what you mean, share your code